# Sonos API - Is it possible to play specific song via API

Tags: sonos

I'm currently integrating the Sonos Control API into our platform.
I successfully integrated "simple" commands related to play/pause, skipToNextTrack, skipToPreviousTrack but is it possible to access associated music provider to the sonos account through the Control API ?
I don't want to integrate a "simple" remote control for Sonos speakers. I would like to use the Spotify, Deezer or whatever associated provider account to search and play a song. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for any reply :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently a possibility with the Control API. We'll bring your request back to the dev team.

Comment: Hello, is there any news about this ?