# Sonos - How to play a Spotify/AppleMusic track on a Sonos device from my iOS app?

Tags: sonos

I'm integrating the Sonos Control API into an iOS app. In our app:

- the user is signed in either to Apple Music or Spotify via an Apple Music subscription or a Spotify premium account.
- the user can play Apple Music and Spotify content within our app (we have the track / album IDs and use this to play music via the Spotiy / Apple Music APIs).
- the user also has the Sonos app installed, and is logged in to their music service of choice (Spotify or Apple Music).

Now when the user is listening to a track in our app, we'd like the user to be able to listen to it via their Sonos device. Our app is for children and has parental control, so the user needs to stay within in our app.

Is there currently any way to achieve this?

Options we've looked into:

1. **Streaming:** As I understand it, there is no way to stream audio to a Sonos device. The [AirPlay-Sonos compatibility](https://blog.sonos.com/en/airplay-is-here/) is not an option as we're targeting all Sonos devices.
2. **Sonos Control API:** We then looked into starting the track using the Spotify or Apple Music track ID via the Sonos Control API, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483067/10895282) answer seems to imply that this is not possible. Is this true even if the user is logged in to the Spotify / Apple Music service both in our app and in the Sonos app? For example I could imagine using [createSession](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/create-session/) with a Spotify / Apple Music accountID so that I would have access to these services, and then using [loadCloudQueue](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/load-cloud-queue/) to load the trackIDs. But I could be misunderstanding the API.
3. **[sonos-objc](https://github.com/getsenic/sonos-objc/tree/master/sonos-objc)**: This looked promising, but is very outdated and we haven't managed to set it up.

Any leads on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, streaming tracks directly to Sonos is not currently supported in our platform. Using music object ids, with their constituent content and account ids, is a vehicle for actual content partners to build direct control integrations with Sonos. iHeart, Pandora, and Tidal have done this for instance.

The reason non-content owners can't utilize this functionality is due to the way authentication is handled. To ensure rights-holders property remains intact, we require partners to execute an account matching flow. This account matching requires direct access to a content partners' auth back end, pretty much limiting these types on integrations to the content partners themselves.

We understand that non-content partners want to put content directly on Sonos, and we're actively looking for the best ways to do that, while still allowing content parters to maintain control of how their content is consumed.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Thanks for clarifying, and good luck.

Comment: @Matt Welch Is that "actively looking for best ways" leading to anything? I've been seeing similar questions for at least two years, but no real answers.